# Why Löwenheim–Skolem theorem asserts the non-existence of such predicates in 1st order logic

Tags: model-theory, foundations, peano-axioms, formal-systems

Suppose there was a predicate, in the language of 1st order $ \mathsf {PA} $, such that it is only true for standard natural numbers i.e. it accepts ALL and ONLY standard natural number, and it **rejects** *any* and *every* non-standard natural number.

Since PA is $ \boldsymbol \omega $-consistent, therefore any such predicate should contradict the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem. But I couldn't find a proof which states such predicates should definitely not exist.

So is there any proof for their non-existence? Or are there any such predicates available, and is there any paper or material that mentions anything about such predicates?

***EDIT*** -  It seems that for some reason @spaceisdarkgreen isn't able to respond to my comments. The answer he gave gets 60% of the question, but there's one part to the question that answer doesn't accounts for - 
Is it true to say that - " **In the intrepretation of any non-standard model** *No such predicates exist ( in 1st order PA
) which are true for* **ALL and ONLY** *standard natural numbers and false for **each and every** non-standard number* " ?

Since in the question I never mentioned about models explicitly, that's because I wanted the answer in general i.e. for all models ( standard and non-standard ) , but in his answer he only refers to standard models, So if anyone can answer this last doubt , so that I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the overspill principle. If there were such a predicate $\varphi(x)$ for some model $M$, then $M\models\varphi(0)$ and $M \models \forall x( \varphi(x)\to \varphi(x+1))$ (since the successor of a standard element is standard), so by the induction schema, $M\models \forall x\varphi(x).$ So the only model with such a predicate is the standard model.

Comment: So, is it true to say that - " **In the intrepretation of any non-standard model** *No such predicates exist ( in 1st order $ \mathsf {PA} $ ) which are true for ALL and ONLY standard natural numbers and false for* **each and every** *non-standard number*  " ?

Comment: i need this doubt to be cleared before i can accept an answer, so do you agree that the above statement is true ?

Comment: can you answer this one doubt regarding  your answer ??

Comment: @AlexMatyasaur it is unreasonable and even a bit rude to expect instantaneous responses from people. you should be patient and respect the time of people answering your questions

Comment: regarding the question you posed in your first comment, yes, that is correct, and that is exactly what spaceisdarkgreen's answer shows. in any model $M$ of PA, if $\phi(x)$ is a formula that holds of all standard natural numbers, then it holds of all elements of $M$. so, unless $M$ is the standard model, $\phi$ cannot hold for precisely the standard natural numbers in $M$